# Get value or ID by clicking on box with specific class

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

I have below code for HTML with laravel foreach loop,

```
                @foreach($tables as $t)
                @if($t->section_id == $s->section_id)
                <div class="col-xl-3 bg-success px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-7 mb-7 my-button">                    
                <div class="text-inverse-succeess font-weight-bolder font-size-h2 mt-3 table" id="{{ $t['table_number']}}"><h2>{{ $t['table_number']}}</h2></div>
                <a href="#" class="text-inverse-success font-weight-bold font-size-lg mt-1">New Products</a>
                </div>  
                @endif
                @endforeach
```

This code will create a box for each table.

Now I want to get **an ID or Table number** when clicking on **my-button** class box. Say there are 10 boxes with table number from 1 to 10, and when I click on the box with table number 5, it should return value 5.

I tried with this way, but it returns all table numbers like 12345678910

```
var table = $('.table').find('h2').text();
console.log(table);
```

How can I achieve this to get table number on click on the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do somethign like this:

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
  var table = "h2 value: " +$('.table h2', this).text();
  var tableid = "table id: " + $('.table', this).attr("id");
  console.log(table);
  console.log(tableid)
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.my-button').click(function() {
  var table = "h2 value: " +$('.table h2', this).text();
  var tableid = "table id: " + $('.table', this).attr("id");
  console.log(table);
  console.log(tableid)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-3 bg-success px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-7 mb-7 my-button">
  <div class="text-inverse-succeess font-weight-bolder font-size-h2 mt-3 table" id="1">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="text-inverse-success font-weight-bold font-size-lg mt-1">New Products</a>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-3 bg-success px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-7 mb-7 my-button">
  <div class="text-inverse-succeess font-weight-bolder font-size-h2 mt-3 table" id="2">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="text-inverse-success font-weight-bold font-size-lg mt-1">New Products</a>
</div>
```